# Not able to scroll till the end in programmatically implemented scrollview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-scrollview

I have implemented scroll view programmatically inside tabbed activity fragment placeholder. My code :

```
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_algorithm, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        String[] array = {"Hi from description", "Hi from C", "Hi from JAVA"};
        array[0] = "Hi! this is the first program of asdk  your carrier into computer coding. This code shows you how to print Hello World on the console of the computer!\n\nHere is the Image ``Image:calender`` \n\nThis image shows you how this program works! Wohoo you learnt the first ``Image:star`` algo of your life.  sdiaj isja dias dsa djsa djas sadksf dsfsdmf sdf ldsf ldsfsdl fsdkf s fsd lksd flsdkl flkds lsdkflklsdk flksdlfklsdl fklsdkl flsdkf klkd b jj bbb jhbhb hjbhj bjh bhjbhjbhjb jbhjb hjbhbhbhjbhbhbhhjb hbhjbh b hjb hj bhjbhj  hb hjb ``Image:youtube`` jh bhjbhjbhjhbh bbhskflkldsl";

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.abcscrollView);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(rootView.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)-1==0) {
            String temparray[] = array[0].split("``");
            array[0] = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < temparray.length; i++) {
                if (temparray[i].startsWith("Image:")) {
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(rootView.getContext());
                    iv.setId(i+1);
                    int itd = this.getResources().getIdentifier(temparray[i].substring(6), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                    iv.setImageResource(itd);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (i > 0) {
                        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
                    }
                    relativeLayout.addView(iv, params1);

                } else {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
                    tv.setText(temparray[i]);
                    tv.setId(i+1);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    if (i > 0) {
                        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
                    }
                    relativeLayout.addView(tv, params1);
                }
                //    array[0]+=temparray[i];
            }
        }
        ScrollView.LayoutParams params2 = new ScrollView.LayoutParams (ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        scrollView.addView (relativeLayout, params2);

        textView.setText (array[getArguments ().getInt (ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1]);
        return rootView;
    }
```

XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.suvariyaraj.algorithms.AlgorithmActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/abcscrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But I am not able to scroll till the end. 
[screenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8eVc.jpg)

Here you can see that the youtube icon is half visible even when the scrollview reaches the end.

Please help me.

Here is the output of "adb shell dumpsys activity top"

```
TASK com.facebook.katana id=2647
ACTIVITY com.facebook.katana/.activity.ImmersiveActivity 431f2cd8 pid=27958
Local FragmentActivity 432394e0 State:
  mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=true mReallyStopped=true
  mLoadersStarted=false
FragmentManager misc state:
  mActivity=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivityHost@4324a178
  mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@432405c0
  mCurState=2 mStateSaved=true mDestroyed=false
View Hierarchy:
  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{43253b08 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
    android.widget.LinearLayout{43254620 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
      android.view.ViewStub{43257f68 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020315}
      android.widget.FrameLayout{432581c8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
        android.view.ViewStub{432589c0 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0a13}
        android.view.ViewStub{43258bc8 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0a0f}
        android.widget.FrameLayout{43258e20 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d04bd app:id/main_container}
          android.widget.FrameLayout{43259158 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d000c app:id/fragment_container}
          com.facebook.ui.titlebar.search.Fb4aFadingTitleBar{432599c8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d00ae app:id/titlebar}
            com.facebook.fbui.glyph.GlyphView{4325ab50 V.ED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d248d app:id/fb_logo_up_button}
            android.widget.FrameLayout{4325afd8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d248e app:id/info_container}
              com.facebook.resources.ui.FbTextView{4325b398 V.ED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0200 app:id/title}
              android.widget.FrameLayout{4325c230 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d248f app:id/custom_title_wrapper}
              android.view.ViewStub{4325c5f0 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d2490}
            android.widget.LinearLayout{4325c888 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d2491 app:id/action_buttons_wrapper}
              com.facebook.fbui.glyph.GlyphView{43262810 V.ED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d02ce app:id/search_button}
        android.view.ViewStub{4325ef30 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0329}
        android.widget.FrameLayout{4325fe90 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d070b app:id/fullscreen_container}
```

Comment: scrollview has only one direct child that is linear layout. so instead of using relative layout use linearlayout and add the elements you want. and set scrollview to android:fillViewPort="true" in the xml file so it will arrange views and make you feel scrollable.

Comment: post the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: @MohammedSameerAhmad I tried to convert relative layout to linear layout but still I am having the same problem.

Comment: @pskink I am using android studio in windows how to run the ADB command in it?

Comment: run it from a terminal window

Comment: @pskink i added the output of the adb command to question please check it

Comment: so where is you scroll view in `View Hierarchy` ? i cannot see it

Comment: @pskink I am a beginner in android, I have implemented it in JAVA programmatically. Code is shown in question Please help me